# c# : Windows Forms : DatagridView : Typing Characters Flickering

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid  view on my form. The user can add as many rows as desired. This datagridview contains 5 columns. I have button called Save on the form through which I loop through all the data grid roes and save them to the database.

The data source is not set at the design time, but through code at run time.

However, when the user is typing in the grid, the characters appear very slowly. Does not match with the typing speed of the user. IT takes atleast a couple of seconds for the typed character to appear. The user does not want to have this since it is not allowing him to verify the typed content immediately, rather it takes a couple of seconds for one character to appear.

Kindly Help on this.

> EDIT 1:
>
> I have painted a Datagridview on the form. This data grid view has a
>   cellclick event that checks for a condition and enables / disables a
>   button on the form.

```
 if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvPrep.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    DataGridViewColumn column = this.dgvPrep.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
                    if (row.Cells["PrepID"].Value != null && row.Cells["PrepID"].Value.ToString() != "0")
                    {
                        if (row.Cells["PrepID"].Value.ToString() != "0" && row.Cells["dgcvStatus"].Value.ToString() == "0")
                        {
                            if (Properties.Settings.Default.ExperimentMultipleEdit == true)
                            {
                               PageHDRBO objPageHDRBO = new PageHDRBO();
                                using (PageHDRBL HDRBL = new PageHDRBL())
                                {
                                    objPageHDRBO = HDRBL.GetPageBL(txtENo.Text);
                                }
                                if (objPageHDRBO.InEditing == OrganisationWide.IsOther_Y && objHDRBO.EditedBy == _empDO.EmployeeID)
                                {
                                    btnSend.Visible = true;
                                }
                                else if (objPageHDRBO.InEditing == OrganisationWide.IsOther_N && objPageHDRBO.EditedBy == null)
                                {
                                    btnSend.Visible = true;
                                }
                             }
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

*The HDRBL.GetPageBL(txtENo.Text); results in a DB query though.*

Comment: I believe there is some loop or validation check being directly applied to your DataGridView while user is interacting with it. Is there anything like that?

Comment: share the code?

Comment: I do have a Cell Click event written.In which I check the column in the row and if is of a certain value then I enable disable buttons on the form. This is an If construct though,.

Comment: Just edit the question and post some codes along with it, this would in-turn help u to get your point straight and for people at SO to give a better solution :)

Comment: Everytime a letter is added/removed in `txtEno` this `HDRBL.GetPageBL(txtENo.Text);` would run the query, in-turn slowing the process in whole.

Comment: But I have written this in the CellClick event. It should not fire when I am typing to the grid, because I am using the Key Board. And txtENo, is a text box on the form not on the gridview.